# Asynchronous Ajax Call Mixing Up Callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

So basically I have an ajax function pretty standard one. Like so:

```
    function ajax_call(rest_req, url, success_callback, fail_callback) {

    // if (request_in_progress)
    //     return;

    // request_in_progress = true;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            // request_in_progress = false;
            if (this.status == 200) {
                success_callback(this);
            }
            else {
                fail_callback(this);
            }
        }
    };

    xhttp.open(rest_req, url, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
```

When I use the ajax function this way:

```
(function() {
 function setup() {
   ajax_call("GET", "url1", function(xhttp) {
        response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        if (response["error"] != 100)
            document.getElementById('url1-reading').innerHTML = '---';
        else
            document.getElementById('url1-reading').innerText = response["response"];
    },
        function() {} 
    );

    ajax_call("GET", "url2" , function(xhttp) {
        response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        if (response["error"] != 100)
            document.getElementById('url2-reading').innerHTML = '---';
        else
            document.getElementById('url2-reading').innerText = response["response"];
    }, 
        function() {}
    );

    console.log('Refresh');

  }

   setInterval(setup, 1000);
  })();
```

This code behaves differently than what I expect. When I run this code, there are some times when the results that were suppose to go to url1 success_callback goes inside url2's success_callback.

To put another way the `response` variable inside url1 ajax_call is what I expected to show up as response variable for url2. So in effect the ajax_call seem to not know what success_callback is for what even though I explicitly pass it in as a parameter.

I'm coming from a C++ background so this is a difficult concept to grasp. How do I do this the right way? I hope my question is clear. Please tell me what is not clear so I can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you declare it, `response` is a global variable. Try changing `response =` to `let response  =`

Comment: It certainly improve things a bit. But there still some occasional where I would see the results for url1 where it's suppose to go for the results of url2

Comment: @user3904534 Are you sure your server handles the concurrent requests properly? Check in the network panel of the devtools whether the responses are actually what you expect.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. There is a bug in the server that makes the response inconsistent. Thank you.